# Sum of array using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>


int arrsum(int *, int *);

int main(void){
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};


    printf("\nSum: %d\n", arrsum(a,a+9));
    return 0;
}

int arrsum(int *p, int *q){
    int sum;
    for(;p<=q;++p){
        sum+=*p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I want to print the sum of elements of array using pointers because I am learning pointers.
When I run this code, I am getting 32811 as output which is wrong.
Please help.

Comment: Does your compiler not issue a warning about uninitialized local variables?

Comment: @Blaze No, it doesn't. There is not warning.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Blaze clang. Sublime text and am compiling in terminal using clang

Comment: Make sure to compile with the `-Wall` option.

Comment: initialize `int sum;` make it `int sum=0`.

Comment: @Blaze I see sum was not initialized. thanks its working now. I ll remember to use that option from now

Comment: Do you expect `55` or `45` as result?

Comment: @mch ya I fixed it. it should be <= in for loop

Comment: @Abhay: You'd better use `<` and pass `a + 10`, because it is idiomatic. In C, ranges are described by an inclusive lower bound `start` and an exclusive upper bound `end`, so that the length of the range is `end - start`. Forward loops look like this: `for (x = start; x < end; x++)`, no matter whether `x` is a pointer or an index.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
int sum;
```

with

```
int sum = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Every statement is write 
Just initialise Sum to any number because a complier assinged a garbage value to Sum .